# AWS Cloudformation DynamoDB Alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am unable to properly create/link a CloudWatch alarm with a DynamoDB Table using CloudFormation.

```
    DynamoDBTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: "Bucket"
            AttributeType: "S"
          -
            AttributeName: "Key"
            AttributeType: "S"
          -
            AttributeName: "IngestedDate"
            AttributeType: "S"  
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: "Bucket"
            KeyType: "HASH"
          - AttributeName: "Key"
            KeyType: "RANGE"
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          -
            IndexName: dateIndex
            KeySchema:
              -
                AttributeName: "Key"
                KeyType: "HASH"
              - AttributeName: "IngestedDate"
                KeyType: "RANGE"
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput: 
              ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacityUnits
              WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacityUnits
        ProvisionedThroughput: 
          ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacityUnits
          WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacityUnits
        TableName: !Join ["-", [!Ref UniqueIdentifier, "Table"]]
    DynamoDBAlarmThroughtputAlarm:
      DependsOn: DynamoDBTable
      Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
      Properties:
        ActionsEnabled: true
        AlarmActions:
          - !Ref ErrorSNSTopic
        AlarmDescription: For when the R/W of a dynamoDB table surpasses a certain throughput. 
        ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold 
        Dimensions:
          -
            Name: Table­Name
            Value: !Ref DynamoDBTable
        EvaluationPeriods: 1
        MetricName: ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits
        Namespace: AWS/DynamoDB
        Period: 300
        Statistic: Average
        Threshold: 1
```

The alarm is able to create but gives the following error message: An error occurred contacting the server.

When "modifying" it, I see that the metric is not selected. Is this a bug?

Regards.

Comment: Seems like you're not [the only one](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241214). Have you tried giving it a couple of hours? Maybe it's just failing whiling getting the initial few data points.

Comment: @kichik Well, I give it more than 12 hours and still the error. Maybe a bug between cloudformation and dynamoDB alarms?

Comment: Exact same problem here.

Comment: ~8 lines up from the bottom, the `TableName` line- looks like you might have a hidden character in there from copying from the AWS console.